# iframe src URL not loading correctly

Tags: cpanel, whm

I developed an online payment gateway, which normally loads in an iframe. Now, the iframe src is not loading in its cPanel environment (Linux server).

I checked the firewall deny IP sections, but the IP is not blacklisted by the server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examine the HTTP Headers being returned from the request, for this header:

X-Frame-Options:

If the site has introduced this header with a value like:

X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

it will prevent the browser from loading an iframe from a different domain. Note that not all browsers make use of this header in the same way:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet#Browser_Support

So simply asking the admins to add your domain to the header with:

x-frame-options: ALLOW-FROM proto://your-payment.domain

is not full solution for Chrome/Safari clients. It would appear you will also need a special CSP bypass in that case. The hosting group would need to add some content security policy to their site to allow your specific frame ancestor:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors

If this is not the issue, perhaps post more HTTP information related to the information flow.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. actually ,when i change my server,then it will be okay. payment  gateway url is embed to iframe through the REST API ,

Comment: Yes,David you are correct it display this message - "Refused to display 'https://www.w3schools.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'."

Comment: If time is an issue I would suggest investigating how you can get the headers removed. Then later it might be a good idea to take the long route, and have them set to specifically allow your payment gateway. I've fiddled with CSP before, but I have never created a work around for this as suggested by the links. I am willing to help though.

Comment: X-Frame-Options is configured at the server level. You need alter the configuration of nginx, apache, jetty, tomcat, IIS, of whichever server is hosting the site. If this is your hosting company it is much easier. If this is managed another group, you will likely need to get in touch with their support group, since it is a server configuration. If you post more details of the HTTP requests it will be easier to understand your specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

Are both the page and iframe source https? An http page will not load an https iframe.

Comment: both are https:// - when i check the code of iframe - it displays "Oh snap! Something wrong in the response. : Please check the internet connection " but its not internet issue